# Quick Sort in java is not correct

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I have been trying to understand what is happening here:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSort {
    static Random random = new Random();

    static void quickSort(int[] arr,
                          int lo,
                          int hi){
        //best case
        if(lo >= hi){return;}

        int pivot = partition(arr,lo,hi);

        quickSort(arr, pivot+1, hi);
        quickSort(arr, lo, pivot-1);
    }

    static int partition(int arr[],
                         int lo,
                         int hi){
        int pivPoz=lo + random.nextInt(hi - lo + 1);
        int pivot = arr[pivPoz];

        int index = lo - 1;

        for(int i = lo;i<=hi; i++){
            if(arr[i] <= pivot && i!=pivPoz ){
                index++;
                int a = arr[index];
                arr[index] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = a;
            }
        }

        index++;
        int a = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[pivPoz];
        arr[pivPoz] = a;

        return index;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int arr[] = new int[]{4,2,8,12,30,1,3,9,10,9,12};
        quickSort(arr,0,arr.length-1);
        for(int i : arr){
            System.out.print(i + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Quick Sort algorithm in Java. I know the code is too lengthy, and I can do it better, but I can do it after I solve this error. I remarked something strange. I am running the same program with the same input but ends with different outcomes, for instance:

1. input = {4,2,8,12,30,1,3,9,10,9,12}
   output = {1  2   3   4   8   9   9   10  12  12  30}
2. input = {4,2,8,12,30,1,3,9,10,9,12}
   output = {8  3   2   4   9   9   10  12  12  30  1}
3. input = {4,2,8,12,30,1,3,9,10,9,12}
   output = {2  4   8   9   9   10  12  3   1   12  30}

I have changed nothing in the code just run it. Do you have any suggestion why this could have happened?

Comment: Try to create an as small as possible failing example and than start debugging.

Comment: That's not what people mean with "not stable" when discussing sort algorithms. What you mean is "incorrect".

Comment: Being stable does mean something else when talking about sorting algorithms. It seems, that your algorithm does in fact not sort them correctly. Stable meaning that elements with the same value stay in the same order. e.g. when sorting the following two elements by value: {value: 1, label: foo} {value:1, label: bar} the element with the label foo stays at an lower index than the element with the label bar.

Comment: @trincot Thank I will edit it and I will put it "incorrect", instead of "stable"

Comment: posted code is using `Random` (almost first line) so no wonder it can return different results on different runs (sure, if the results were correctly soreted, that would not matter)

Comment: @user85421, there is no problem with using random. Many Quicksort variants use it with success.

Comment: From question, emphasis added: "I am running the **same** program with the **same** input but ends with **different** outcomes" - using `Random` should explain why (as long as the sorting is not correctly working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your Lomuto-like algorithm, you leave the pivot within the range that is being iterated. You *do* have some precaution with `i != pivPoz`, but that still leaves some room for problems when `index` overtakes `pivPoz`:

When `index++` makes `index` equal to `pivPoz`, the pivot is swapped to another index, and so you will lose track of where the pivot is, and return the wrong index.

The usual way to avoid these problems is to first swap the randomly selected pivot to the right end of the range, so it is at index `hi`. This index is then excluded from the loop, and you'll not have this problem occurring.

Here is your `partition` code with that correction (I also moved the swap-logic in a separate function):

```
    static void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    
    static int partition(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
        swap(arr, lo + random.nextInt(hi - lo + 1), hi);
        int pivot = arr[hi];
        int index = lo - 1;
        for(int i = lo; i < hi; i++) {
            if (arr[i] <= pivot) swap(arr, ++index, i);
        }
        swap(arr, ++index, hi);
        return index;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not tough about that I learned something new. PS: Thank you for the java code, after you explain it I realised and I chained the code and after I commented and then I show your code lol