# java quick sort time limit

Tags: java, quicksort, time-limiting

**This code sometimes works okey, but in some tests it`s Time Limit. What`s the mistake?**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        int[] A = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        QuickSort(A, 0, N - 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            System.out.print(A[j] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int Partition(int[] A, int l, int r) {
        int x = (int)(Math.random() * (r - l + 1) + l);
        int Z = A[l];
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            if (A[i] < Z) {
                Z = A[i];
            }
        }
        while (A[x] == Z) {
            x = (int)(Math.random() * (r - l + 1) + l);
        }
        int C = l - 1;
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            int y = A[i];
            if (y >= A[x]) {
                continue;
            }
            if (y < A[x]) {
                int fake = A[C+1];
                A[C+1] = A[i];
                A[i] = fake;
                ++C;
            }
        }
        return C + 1;
    }
    public static int[] QuickSort(int[] A, int l, int r){
        if (r - l + 1 <= 1) {
            return A;
        }
        if (l < r) {
            int Index = Partition(A, l, r);
            QuickSort(A, l,  Index - 1);
            QuickSort(A, Index, r);
        }
        return A;
    }
}
```

I tried to check short arrays like {3,2,1} or {3,7,4,2,1,9} it`s ok, but if it`s 40 or 100 numbers -> TimeLimit. I create partition algorithm, and take random pivot. After this, I check if random number equal min, change it. I count numbers of iterations and make QuickSort for left side and right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the (sub)array being partitioned has only the same value repeated, like [2, 2, 2], or [5, 5], the following loop will never exit:

```
    while (A[x] == Z) {
        x = (int)(Math.random() * (r - l + 1) + l);
    }
```

You have added this code (and the loop to find `Z`) to avoid that the partitioncut happens at the extreme left, leaving the caller with an empty partition and another partition that has the same size as before.

But there are other ways to ensure that. For instance, you could swap the pivot element into the (otherwise) empty partition.

Today another question on random pivot selection came up. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201965/5459839) over there may be an inspiration to you.

Comment: How I can change this? If I delete this while, one situation can happen, when pivot equal min arr, and it will be infinity recursion at quick sort (Index = l, and QuickSort (A,l,r) returns QuickSort (A,l,r).

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Did that answer your question?